# Extract a content of a html page in php

Tags: php, html-content-extraction

There is any way to extract the content of a `HTML` page that starts from `<body>` and ends with `</body>` in php. If there can anyone post some sample code.

Comment: See one of the many website crawling questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) reference.

This example reads a html document, creates a `DOMDocument` and gets the body tag:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

echo $body->textContent; // print all the text content in the body
```

You should also check out the following resources:

[DOM API Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
[XPATH language specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)

Answer (score 2):

Try [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
$body = $html->find('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use non-DOM solution based on `strpos` function:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = substr($html,stripos($html,'<body>')+6);
$html = substr($html,0,strripos($html,'</body>'));
```

`stripos` is case insensitive version of `strpos`, `strripos` is case insensitive 'rightmost position' version of `strpos`.

Hope that it will help you!